# What does "build on" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the following, does "build on" mean "change"?

> Also, Bitcoin is recorded on a public blockchain that allows anyone to build on it. On the other hand, to build on many features of Libra’s blockchain, developers must seek permission from Facebook and its partners who administer it.

Source:http://fortune.com/2019/06/18/facebook-project-libra-crypto-coin-cryptocurrency-how-it-works/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build on in this case would mean to use the blockchain as a "base" to build your software. (For example, building new tools to manage libra). Software Engineers can, with permission of facebook, create new software that uses the libra.